# Automated e-mail based on SQL results

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, sendmail

We need to write a BASH script to perform a SQL query and then send an automated e-mail using some of the results. Our SQL version is Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.4.0 and the SELECT statement to get the results that we want is:

```
SELECT kred_lim.kunr, kust_adr.ku_email, kred_lim.kred_limit, kred_lim.kred_zu_zahlen
FROM kred_lim, kust_adr
WHERE kred_lim.kred_zu_zahlen > kred_lim.kred_limit
AND kred_lim.kunr = kust_adr.ku_nr;
```

So this will show the customer number, customer e-mail address, credit limit and current outstanding orders value limited to customers who's outstanding orders value is greater than their credit limit. We are just stuck on where to start, or how to incorporate those results into an e-mail.

We just need a simple e-mail sent to each one, explaining that they're over their credit limit and showing their credit limit and current outstanding orders value in that e-mail.

Any examples or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to use sqlplus? Do you know how to capture the output of a command in bash?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes I know how to use SQL*Plus to get the results that need to be used, I've put the `SELECT` statement above. I am looking for examples of how to perform the query in a BASH script, e-mail each row using the e-mail address returned and include both amounts (`kred_limit` and `kred_zu_zahlen`) somewhere in the e-mail.

Answer (score 2):

I would write:

```
#!/bin/bash

sql="
    set pagesize 0
    set feedback 0

    SELECT kred_lim.kunr ||','|| kust_adr.ku_email ||','|| kred_lim.kred_limit ||','|| kred_lim.kred_zu_zahlen
    FROM kred_lim, kust_adr
    WHERE kred_lim.kred_zu_zahlen > kred_lim.kred_limit
    AND kred_lim.kunr = kust_adr.ku_nr;
"

email_template="Subject: Credit limit
To: %s

Customer number: %s
Credit limit: %s
Current orders: %s
"

sqlplus $user/$pass@$db <<< "$sql" |
while IFS=, read -r num email limit orders; do
    printf "$email_template" "$email" "$num" "$limit" "$orders" |
    /path/to/sendmail -f sender@example.com -oi -t
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, that's great. I seem to get a lot of 'No recipient addresses found in header' error messages when running that. There are some customers that do not have an e-mail address set but the majority do. There are customers that should have had an e-mail sent however when checking the `maillog` it appears nothing was sent. Would the fact that some customers do not have an e-mail address set cause the problem?

Comment: Also, do you know if it would be possible using BASH to remember what customers (or e-mail addresses) have been sent this e-mail and ignore them for a fixed period of time, or would such checks have to be done outside of BASH? For e.g., if a customer has been sent an e-mail in the last 24 hours then ignore them, or something along those lines.

Comment: I would store the last email sent time in the database (using sqlplus and an insert or update). Then you can build that into your query for the next run. In the while loop you can add `if [[ -n $email ]];` to see the email is non-empty before you attempt to send. I can't help you diagnose your mail system.

Comment: The 'No recipient addresses found in header' error message would suggest that there is an issue in your code, not `sendmail`, as that works ok.

Comment: Just found the problem in the code: I was using single quotes for the sql string, and the inner single quotes would have been lost.